# Maximum Coordinates Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, coordinates

I'm studying Cocos2d  for iPhone and I have a problem:

I would like to get the maximum value of the coordinates x and y in the screen.

I have tried to use :

```
CGRectGetMaxX([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]);
```

but in this case it doesn't work.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]
```

should return a `CGSize` with the size of the screen. So you can get the 'maximum' x and y with.-

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int maxX = winSize.width - 1;
int maxY = winSize.height - 1;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.take advantage of the situation for asking you: what is the difference between the screen size and pixels? In particular , if I have a device with 320x160 it has 320 pixels about X and 160 about Y ?

Comment: That's right. Take 'screen size' as the number of pixels the device has to render your graphics. By the way, welcome to stackoverflow, if the answer was helpful, please, consider upvoting/accepting as may be useful for other users too :)

Comment: ok,I understood.Sorry but I have other question for you: what is the difference between the maximum X value and the width of the screen?

Comment: They are 'almost' the same. The width is the total amount of 'horizontal' pixels; since they're accounted from zero, the last pixel (maximum x) is screenWidth - 1

Comment: Ok now it's very clear but reading this article: http://finalwavestudios.com/understanding-cocos2d-the-basics           I want to know the difference between point and pixel

Comment: Have you even tried googling something like "cocos2d points"?